# Pre-computing large table of values

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a mathematical formula in my program that takes in two values, both between 0 and 1, and does a lot of work to find an answer.

I also want to be able to do the inverse, i.e. I want to know what input values will produce a certain output. I cannot do this analytically, as the same answer can be produced from numerous inputs and the formulas are too complex anyway.

My problem is that I am currently doing something like this, which takes fairly long to compute

```
  for(double i = 0; i <= 1 ; i += 0.0001)
      for(double j = 0; j <= 1; j+= 0.0001)
           answer = formula(i,j); //do the math
           if( Math.abs(answer - answerWanted) < 0.001)
                //close match found
```

Seeing as the formulas are static, I could surely pre compute these values. I presume it would then be much quicker to look up a value than to perform many calculations.

I have never done anything like this before. Does anyone know what data structures to use/ how to index/ how to store the results? At the moment my only thoughts are that I could somehow sort the answers to reduce the search space or else just initializing a huge array at runtime. If it matters, the answer can only range between 0 and 2000.

Comment: What's the range of possible output values? And what type?

Comment: Will your inputs always be multiples of 0.0001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have a 10,000 by 10,000 array of `double` values.  That will occupy roughly 800Mb of Java heap memory if you keep it in memory.

Here are some strategies that might help:

- Keep the data in a database table.  You could probably achieve sub-millisecond access times (depending on database product, tuning, access patterns, etc), and an in-memory cache would improve things.  Assuming that you stored `{i, j, value}` triples, you'd need to index on `{i, j}` for the forward lookups, and `{value}` for the inverse function.
- If the formula is continuous and relatively smooth, you could reduce the number of data points stored (e.g. to 1000 by 1000), and use interpolation to give you approximate values for the in-between data points.
- If the formula doesn't have local minima and maxima, you could use a variation on hill-climbing to calculate the inverse function.

---

In all of this, you need to consider that the inverse function is unlikely to be a 1-to-1 function.  There are likely to be values that appear at multiple `{i, j}` points, and possibly other values for which the function is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a more intelligent search algorithm. The best choice will depend on your function, but a good start will probably be the Nelder-Mead (Downhill Simplex) algorithm:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder–Mead_method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method)

This will greatly reduce the number of calculations. Local minima can be a problem for some search algorithms but Nelder-Mead can get out of many/most of these.

If you find you are searching the same values repeatedly, you can then also add a simple caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the values in a database and use a search to match it. Databases use indexes which make searching faster.

Suppose you have a table which has formula and value as columns, you could use a range selector such as

```
select formula, value from pre_computed_values 
    where value >= givenvalue - Epsilon and value <= givenvalue - Epsilon
```

where Epsilon is a very small value (the range which you are happy with eg 0.001 in your case)

Comment: Do you need a "+ Epsilon" in that where clause?

Answer (score 0):

How complex is the formula? If it does not alternate increasing and decreasing rapidly, you could change your increment value to something bigger than .0001 and then bound the answer by using successively smaller increments once you know two values the answer you want is in between

If you are set on compiling a list of possible outcomes with corresponding inputs, might I suggest a hash table. The access time is O(1) and therefore all you would have to worry about is space requirements and the time it takes to create the table.

Comment: Space requirements are ~10Gb.  See calculations above.

Comment: Unless the formula is smooth enough to where you can reduce the required data set down to a manageable size and then trap the answer as described above. 10GB sounds a little large to save unless you have that space to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Hash Map from Double to `Set<Pair<Double, Double>>`

`HashMap<Double, Set<Pair<Double, Double>> Answers;`

```
// fill in answers
for(double i = 0; i <= 1 ; i += 0.0001)
    for(double j = 0; j <= 1; j+= 0.0001) {
        answer = formula(i,j);
     Set<Double> existing;
        if (Answers.hasKey(answer)) {
          existing = Answers.get(answer);
        }
        else {
          existing = new Set<Pair<Double, Double>>;
       }
       existing.add(new Pair(i, j));
       Answers.set(answer, existing);
    }
}
```

`// look up all the possible inputs for an answer`

`Set<Pair<Double, Double>> inputs = Answers.get(output);`

I haven't considered inverses but that is straightforward...

Comment: That's probably not going to work, as-is.  Considering that the forward function takes ~800Mb when represented as a matrix, the inverse function represented as a hash table is likely to take ~10Gb.  (If you include object headers, the keys will take 16 bytes each, the values will take 16 bytes each, the Map.Entry's will take 28+ bytes each, the hash array will have 50-100 million entries ...)

Comment: I'd like to try this, perhaps If I were to lower the resolution it might be plausible. However, I can't seem to get `existing = new Set<Pair<Double, Double>>;` to work. How do I allocate the memory I don't know

Comment: @Stephen C: hardware problem :-)

Comment: @Roger: You'll Have to define the pair class yourself as Java doesn't come with one...  Look for help with defining a class that can be stored in a Set, you'll need to implement an interface (Comparable, i believe).

Comment: Oops - even more, if you use `Pair<Double, Double>` instead of a custom `Pair` class with `double` fields.  Now we're talking about ~56 bytes per value.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility depends on the nature of the equation--if a graph of the output vs the input values doesn't contain discontinuities or other such ugliness you can precompute a much coarser array (avoiding the 400+ megabytes of storing the array you are looking at) and then attempt to converge on an answer.

Precalculate a coarser grid than you are looking at and then attempt to refine your answer by taking a stepping interval of half your grid size and examining (you'll have to calculate them) the eight neighboring spots.  Choose the best, cut your grid in half and repeat until you have the desired accuracy.  This causes 8 calculations per step (you always have the center value from the previous step), to go from a 100x100 to your resolution takes only 7 steps for a total of 56 calls to your calculations function.

The coarse grid only needs to be fine enough that you can't end up trapped on the wrong side of a saddle from your objective.

Even at a 1000x1000 grid you're looking at a max of 8 megabytes for the grid and 32 calculations to converge it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) for finding function's input value for given output.

hth

Comment: With only two parameters, this would be a very poor way of doing things.